# Yarn start / npm start both are not opening development server

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I'm not able to start development server with yarn as well as npm.

- `yarn start` gives this output:

  [image: yarn start]
- and here's problem with `npm start`:
  [npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPSTp.png)

I'm currently in middle of a React project and it was working fine until now and I have no what went wrong.

Comment: It looks like you have a permissions issue. You might try verifying you have access to the file it indicates in the message on your current user.  I don't recognize the file as the normal npm config so you may also want to verify your version of npm is up to date.

Comment: That is actually my fault, I forgot to change the screenshot for `npm start` but it was totally a different issue and its solved now yet its not working. Also if that was the main issue `yarn start` should still work. thanks for pointing out though, I'll change it.